# How do I remove the some parts of a file name for many files in Windows 7 using batch script?

Tags: windows-7, rename, batch-rename

I have some jsp file which need to rename. it has _h5 prefix. SO i need to remove that _h5 and make the file.

ex: Account_h5.jsp to Account.jsp

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Powershell set up you can do it like this:

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_h5","" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there any way to call this is recursive way. Than mean this folder as same as sub folders?